# reading and modifying large text files 3-5GB

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter, file-handling

I have a rather large file consisting of several million lines and there is the need to check and remove corrupt lines from the file.

I have shamelessly tried `File.ReadAllLines` but it didn't work. Then I tried to stream lines as below reading from the original file and writing to a new one. While it does the job, it does so in several hours(5+). I have read about using buffers which sounds like the only option but how am I going to keep line integrity in that way?

**Solution:** StreamWriter moved to outside of while. Instead of split, count is used.

```
 using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead((localFileToProcess + ".txt")))
 {
    using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1254)))
    {
       using(StreamWriter writer=new StreamWriter(localFileToProcess,true,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1254)))
       {
          while (!inputReader.EndOfStream)
          {
             if ((tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()).Count(c => c == ';') == 4)
             {
                 writer.WriteLine(tempLineValue);
             }
             else
                 incrementCounter();
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Split(';') allocates an array and creates 5 strings in memory per each line. This adds work for a garbage collector. Maybe you should just check that there are 4 semicolons in your line? Also each iteration you are creating/disposing StreamWriter. Isn't it better to create one at the beginning and dispose in the end of operation?

Comment: good point. I'll make the changes.

Comment: how about reading a batch into a string builder, process and then write in one go ?

Comment: @Artemix Tried your suggestion and got 5+ hours to 15 mins drop. Just going to try bhs' suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the slowest part in your original code was the creating/disposing StreamWriter. On each Dispose the StreamWriter had to flush all unwritten data to the disc, close file handles, etc. On open OS had to check security permissions, current locks an do many other things as well.

When you started to use only one StreamWriter, its internal write buffer began to work  writing the data to the disk in large chunks. Along with skipping closing/opening file for writing this saves a lot of time. Disk I/O is usually the slowest part in application.

Split(';') also had possible speed impact, but I think it was less significant. Anyway, string operations should be done carefully in C#, because strings are immutables and can create a lot of garbage in memory. So, if you can check for a 4 semicolons it is always better than call Split(';') which allocates an array and (in your case) creates 5 strings in memory per each line. When a lot of string operations are performed using immutable strings it may severily hit application performance even without any disc I/O.

As for using StringBuilder in your case - I don't think it helps much, because StreamWriter already has built-in buffering.